# convergence or divergence of Irrational series.

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Finding convergence or divergencs of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}$$

What i try::

$$\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}\approx 2n^4$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}\approx \sqrt{2}\; n^2$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}\approx \sqrt{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n^2$$

Seems that it is divergent.

But i did not justified How do i prove it.Thanks

Comment: The $n-$th term is NOT tending to $0$ so divergent. $$\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5} \geq \frac{4n^6}{2n^2+n^2+n^2}=n^4$$ for $n \geq 3$

Answer (score 1):

The sucession in your series verifies that:
$$\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}>0 \text{  (trivial for $n\in\mathbb{N}$),}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4n^3}{2n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2n^2=\infty.$$
So, given this (positive and going to infinity) we conclude that:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sqrt{\frac{4n^6+3n}{2n^2+n+5}}=\infty.$$